# How to create multiple document roots on server?

Tags: php, apache

I am developing a website where if a user enters any sub-domain the system changes to look within a specific folder within root. I can get to the files correctly, however because the document root is looking for /server-path/ as the root, none of my files, images etc work.

Here is my file structure if this helps:

For `www.main-website.com`,
The Server doc root = `/server-path/`

For `subdomain.main-website.com`
system looks at -> `/server-path/folder/`

The Server Doc Root still = `/server-path/` - however I need this to now equal `/server-path/folder` as the DOC ROOT.

I have tried the following with no success:

1. Setting the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to equal **/server-path/folder**
2. Adding a php.ini file into the folder root with the following line:

`doc_root = "/server-path/folder"`

I'm not very competent with Apache or server changes so any help / suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

You can set different document roots by using VirtualHost

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.main-website.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName subdomain.main-website.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Tipically this content should be included into a .conf file inside /etc/httpd/conf.d/

Comment: Hi Raul, thanks for the reply but I don't think I've been explicit enough. I used 'subdomain.main-website.com' as an example URL. There could be anything in front of the main URL so you could have test.website.com, example.website.com, something.wesbite.com. Is this possible or not? Thanks again